# Need to configure redirect_URI on SoundCloud

Tags: soundcloud, api-authorization

I am now getting an unauthorized message with my PHP SoundCloud App like that is described in:
[Soundcloud API authentication always throws "401 - Unauthorized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459401/soundcloud-api-authentication-always-throws-401-unauthorized)

After much reading, I understand that what my App needs is an authorization code. To get one of those, I need a redirect_url configured in the App settings on SoundCloud. I don't have one.

My question is: where do I go and to whom do I ask to do this? It is not possible to do from the Web UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to find out how to get my redirect_uri changed.

I was directed to this link:   https://github.com/soundcloud/api#how-can-i-update-my-apps-redirect_uri.

There is a heading there: How can I update my app's redirect_uri.

Click the link there. This will take you to a SoundCloud Support Chat box. In that chatbox, you can put your question, your client id, email and redirect_uri. The answer should come in an email.

Happy Appy'ing

Comment: Where did you get client_id if you dont have app on soundcloud?